# best gem for login system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rubygems

which is the best gem for creating a login system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tryed many and authlogic is imho the best http://rdoc.info/projects/binarylogic/authlogic
Very rich featured and easy to use.

Comment: authlogic is good! thank you...

Answer (score 8):

[Here is a good comparison of Rails authentication systems](http://www.themomorohoax.com/2009/02/21/rails-2-3-authentication-comparison).

I went with [Devise/Warden](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) - it's working well for me at the moment. Make sure you go with the correct version for your version of Rails - the default Devise version is only for Rails 3, but you can get the Rails 2.x version as well (with `gem install devise --version=1.0.8`).

Comment: +1 for devise, good community/support

Comment: Any updates? This is for Rails 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Clearance works well for me. Easy implementation and very little fuss.

I'd also give Devise/Warden a +1. Very powerful.